# Convert string to base 64 from sha1 Hash in Python

Tags: c#, python

I have a small C# function that I want to use in Python. However Im not sure how to use hashlib to accomplish the same result. The function receives a string an returns the base64 encoding of the sha1 hash of the string:

```
private string ConvertStringToHash(string word)
{
  return Convert.ToBase64String(new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(word)));
}
```

I tried this on python but im not getting the same results:

```
def convert_string_to_hash(word):
    m1 = hashlib.sha1()
    m1.update(word)
    res = m1.digest()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(res)
    return encoded
```

Whats the best way to accomplish the same thing in Python?

Comment: Can you post some sample input word and your expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in the output stems from the encoding you are using:

- in your C# code, [`UnicodeEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) encodes the input string (`word`) as UTF-16 little endian; and
- in your Python code, you're not even handling Unicode strings (they must be encoded as *some* bytes)

So, just encode the `word` as [UTF-16 little endian](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) before hashing:

```
import hashlib
import base64

def convert_string_to_hash(word):
    digest = hashlib.sha1(word.encode('utf-16-le')).digest()
    return base64.b64encode(digest)
```

Also, your Python function can be somewhat shortened.

Comment: Thank you very much! Outputs now match perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me for storing in LDAP. Hex matched, but it was that base64 encode that brought it over the line - python3.

```
    newSaUserPassword = "{SHA256}" + \
                        base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(options.newSaUserPassword.encode("utf-8")).digest())
```